# Using one data frame to sum a range of data from another data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm migrating from SAS to R. I need help figuring out how to sum up weather data for date ranges. In SAS, I take the date ranges, use a data step to create a record for every date (with `startdate`, `enddate`, `date`) in the range, merge with weather and then summarize (VAR hdd cdd; CLASS=startdate enddate sum=)  to sum up the values for the date range.

R code:

```
startdate <- c(100,103,107)
enddate <- c(105,104,110)
billperiods <-data.frame(startdate,enddate);
```

to get:

```
> billperiods
startdate enddate
1       100     105
2       103     104
3       107     110
```

R code:

```
weatherdate <- c(100:103,105:110)
hdd <- c(0,0,4,5,0,0,3,1,9,0)
cdd <- c(4,1,0,0,5,6,0,0,0,10)
weather <- data.frame(weatherdate,hdd,cdd)
```

to get:

```
> weather
   weatherdate hdd cdd
1          100   0   4
2          101   0   1
3          102   4   0
4          103   5   0
5          105   0   5
6          106   0   6
7          107   3   0
8          108   1   0
9          109   9   0
10         110   0  10
```

Note: `weatherdate = 104` is missing. I may not have weather for a day.

I can't figure out how to get to:

```
> billweather
  startdate enddate sumhdd sumcdd
1       100     105      9     10
2       103     104      5      0
3       107     110     13     10
```

where `sumhdd` is the sum of the `hdd`'s from `startdate` to `enddate` in the weather `data.frame`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method using `IRanges` and `data.table`. Seemingly, for this question, this answer may seem kind of an overkill. But in general, I find it convenient to use `IRanges` to deal with intervals, how simple they may be.

```
# load packages
require(IRanges)
require(data.table)

# convert data.frames to data.tables
dt1 <- data.table(billperiods)
dt2 <- data.table(weather)

# construct Ranges to get overlaps
ir1 <- IRanges(dt1$startdate, dt1$enddate)
ir2 <- IRanges(dt2$weatherdate, width=1) # start = end

# find Overlaps
olaps <- findOverlaps(ir1, ir2)

# Hits of length 10
# queryLength: 3
# subjectLength: 10
#    queryHits subjectHits 
#     <integer>   <integer> 
#  1          1           1 
#  2          1           2 
#  3          1           3 
#  4          1           4 
#  5          1           5 
#  6          2           4 
#  7          3           7 
#  8          3           8 
#  9          3           9 
#  10         3          10 

# get billweather (final output)
billweather <- cbind(dt1[queryHits(olaps)], 
                dt2[subjectHits(olaps), 
                list(hdd, cdd)])[, list(sumhdd = sum(hdd), 
                sumcdd = sum(cdd)), 
                by=list(startdate, enddate)]

#    startdate enddate sumhdd sumcdd
# 1:       100     105      9     10
# 2:       103     104      5      0
# 3:       107     110     13     10
```

**Code breakdown for last line:** First I construct using `queryHits`, `subjectHits` and `cbind` a mid-way `data.table` from which then, I group by `startdate, enddate` and get the sum of `hdd` and sum of `cdd`. It is easier to look at the line separately as shown below for better understanding.

```
# split for easier understanding
billweather <- cbind(dt1[queryHits(olaps)], 
            dt2[subjectHits(olaps), 
            list(hdd, cdd)])
billweather <- billweather[, list(sumhdd = sum(hdd), 
            sumcdd = sum(cdd)), 
            by=list(startdate, enddate)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
billweather <- cbind(billperiods, 
                 t(apply(billperiods, 1, function(x) { 
                   colSums(weather[weather[, 1] %in% c(x[1]:x[2]), 2:3])
               })))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried it against the bigger data frame (12,356 rows) and it took 7.89 seconds and the results are good! I'm surprised how fast people responded. This is the first time I asked a question in here.

Answer (score 1):

```
 cbind(billperiods, t(sapply(apply(billperiods, 1, function(x) 
     weather[weather$weatherdate >= x[1] & 
             weather$weatherdate <= x[2], c("hdd", "cdd")]), colSums)))

  startdate enddate hdd cdd
1       100     105   9  10
2       103     104   5   0
3       107     110  13  10
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried it against the bigger data frame (12,356 rows) and it took 6.75 seconds and the results are good!